# What's the standard file structure of a Ruby project?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Assuming I'm creating a vanilla Ruby project that isn't necessarily a web project, what should  my file structure look like?  My requirements are:

- Has a mechanism for including gems (Gemfile in the root most likely)
- Allows me to run the Ruby file directly but also can serve as a library

My stab at the idea is:

```
proj
--> .ruby-version
--> .ruby-gemset
--> lib
----> proj.rb
--> Gemfile
--> README
--> run.rb (which requires the proj.rb in lib/ and uses it to do work)
```

Are there any considerations I should take into account if I plan to make a Ruby Gem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't necessarily any set way to define a Ruby project. But, generally RubyGems have this file structure:

```
.
├── bin
│   └── mygem
├── Gemfile
├── lib
│   ├── mygem
│   │   └── version.rb
│   └── mygem.rb
├── LICENSE
├── mygem.gemspec
├── Rakefile
└── README.md
```

Of course, there is also other directories and files in the project root, for tests, `.ruby-version`, etc.

Comment: Thanks!  If `/bin/mygem` is pure Ruby, is it still convention to keep it as `mygem` and not `mygem.rb`?

Comment: Yes, all files in `bin` usually should not have an extension. But remember to add a Ruby shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env ruby`) to the file.